# Electron Hiccup on heavy calculation in the Main Process

Tags: node.js, electron, ipc

I am building an electron App. I am wondering whether the renderer processes and main process are really separate processes. Sometimes when I do heavy calculations in the main process, it causes the renderer process (the window and its content) to become unresponsive for a split second; some CSS animations get stalled.

Is it normal? Is there any workaround to avoid this 'hiccup'?

Answer (score 1):

The main process and the renderer process are not really different processes.
You can read more about this topic here: [The horrors of Electrons main process](https://medium.com/actualbudget/the-horror-of-blocking-electrons-main-process-351bf11a763c)

If you have heavy calculations, you can create a new background window, make it invisible and do the calculations there:

```
backgroundWindow = new BrowserWindow({show : false});
```